# How can I get the position of the captured groups?

Tags: python, regex

The example:

```py
r = re.search("a(..)d(.)f", "xxabcdefg")
```

`r.span()` returns `(2, 8)` the entire string

but I would like to get the start and end positions of the two captured groups, so `(2, 4)` and `(6, 7)`.

Comment: You mean `(3, 5)` for the first group? `(2, 4)` is `ab`, not `bc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `r.span()` method takes a *group* parameter; each group is numbered, so use `1` and `2` to get the spans of the two groups, `0` for the whole text (where `0` is the default):

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.search("a(..)d(.)f", "xxabcdefg")
>>> r.span()
(2, 8)
>>> r.span(1)
(3, 5)
>>> r.span(2)
(6, 7)
```

From the [`MatchObject.span()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.span) documentation:

> `span([group])`
>   For `MatchObject` *m*, return the 2-tuple `(m.start(group), m.end(group))`. Note that if *group* did not contribute to the match, this is `(-1, -1)`. *group* defaults to zero, the entire match.